# Got Breeze.js working wth odata4 and olingo?

Tags: angularjs, odata, breeze, olingo

the apache olingo javascript library is out of beta and has been released. So using odata 4 with breeze could be possible already. I didn't find any news on the internet.

I'd like to get it working in an angularjs application.

Comment: Welcome to SO @kjartan. Unfortunately your question is at the moment not clearly solveable.
In theory it should be possible to combine olingo and breeze (In fact it was  also at least partly possible during beta phase)
But practily you need to show at least some effort to post your question on SO. We gladly would like to help you with your specific problems - but for this purpose you need to clearly substantiate your problems.

Comment: Breeze itself does not yet support OData 4. Please see the following for an OData 4 adapter for breeze that ties into the olingo library: https://github.com/tschettler/breezejs-odata4-adapter